# Android Beam LLCP Protocol

Tags: android, nfc, android-beam

I am attempting to communicate with my Galaxy S III and a micro-controller that features a PN532 NFC chip.

As this is a micro-controller there is no default LLCP library that I can use so I must understand the Android protocol myself.

Could anyone clarify for me, when I first place the phone to the device, what packets to expect from the very first step? Assuming I am parsing correctly I am seeing:

```
DSAP: 3F
PTYPE: 0
SSAP: 0
```

and also

```
DSAP: 1E
PTYPE: C
SSAP: 0
```

Is this along the right lines? What is Android attempting to do? I would have expected a connection attempt prior to an information package?

Many thanks for any clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Android is using the [NDEF Push Protocol (NPP)](http://source.android.com/compatibility/ndef-push-protocol.pdf) (PDF) on top of LLCP for Android Beam.

Therefore, you have to implement both LLCP ([official spec download](http://www.nfc-forum.org/specs/spec_list/), [mirror in Korea](http://nfckorea.tistory.com/entry/Logical-Link-Control-Protocol-Technical-Specification-pdf-5027kB)) and NDEF-Push on top of it.
Starting with API level 14, Android also uses SNEP alternatively to NPP, but [can fall back automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10823231).

Comment: this link to old LLCP spec, any1 have LLCP 1.2 spec link ?